# react native text component should not be larger than parent view component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Requirement:

[image]

I want to create the link badge.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

import HyperLinkIcon from '../../icons/hyperlink-icon';
import RemoveBadgeItemIcon from '../../icons/remove-item-badge-icon';

import {Colors, Typography, Fonts} from '../../theme';

const ItemBadge = ({
  url = 'http://www.koovs.com/itemhttp://www.koovs.com/item',
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.badgeContainer}>
     
      <HyperLinkIcon />

      <View style={styles.urlContainerStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.urlStyle} numberOfLines={1}>
          {url}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <RemoveBadgeItemIcon />
      
    </View>
  );
};

export default ItemBadge;

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  badgeContainer: {
    padding: 14,
    borderRadius: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#F0EFFF',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },

  urlContainerStyle: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 14,
  },

  urlStyle: {
    color: Colors.LABEL,
    fontSize: Typography._14,
    fontFamily: Fonts.ROMAN,
  },
});
```

But this gives me this:

[image]

I am trying to make `Text` component's maxWidth equal to that of its parent `View` and also if the url is long then it gets ellipsis.

Responsiveness should also be taken into consideration.

Comment: inside `badgeContainer ` add this `marginHorizontal: 14,`

Comment: @TusharPandey `badgeContainer` is my outermost `View` i don't need margin on it. Thw whole page already has padding on both sides and `badgeContainer` takes the full available space. For the spacing between icon and text the `urlContainerStyle` has padding on both sides. Problem is my `Text` is pushing the right icon out of `badgeContainer`.